# How can i get the variable value in my second call in PHP?

Tags: php, behat

I have used both Global and Static variables to make the value available in second call . but it gives me same error .

```
public function iCheckTimeStampofAjaxAndLite($Version,$Date)
 {
 $node = $this->getMainContext()->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', $Date); 
 print_r("Count:" .sizeof($node)); echo "\n"; 
 $DateText=(string)$node->getText(); 
 if ($Version=='Ajax'){
  static $AjaxDate;
  $AjaxDate=$DateText;
  print_r("AjaxDate:" .$AjaxDate); echo "\n";
  return;
 }
 else{
  if ($AjaxDate==$DateText){
    print_r("DateText:" .$DateText); echo "\n";
          return;
  }
  else{
    throw new Exception("Both Date are not Same");
  }
 }
}


1st call -> iCheckTimeStampofAjaxAndLite("Ajax","1.50pm");
2nd call -> iCheckTimeStampofAjaxAndLite("Lite","3.50pm");

Output : (Notice: Undefined variable: AjaxDate)
```

Comment: Please learn what [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your  private `$ajaxDate` in your class:

```
private $ajaxDate;
```

Also change:

```
//...

else{
  if ($AjaxDate=$DateText){
    print_r("DateText:" .$DateText); echo "\n";
          return;
  }
//...
```

into

```
//...

else if ($AjaxDate==$DateText){
    print_r("DateText:" .$DateText); echo "\n";
          return;
  }
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `static` for this, using properties of the class is much nicer.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
class FeatureContext
{
    private $ajaxDate;

    // ...

    public function iCheckTimeStampofAjaxAndLite($Version,$Date)
    {
        // ...
        $this->ajaxDate = ...; // set the ajax date

        var_dump($this->ajaxDate); // use the ajax date
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "does not exist_s_ in PHP". http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: @Numbers I've learned something new, thanks. Removed it from the answer